# How to parse time ? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

In a form, users have to input a time data manually. Unfortunately, front end developer forgot to validate the date input. Therefore, users wrote the time without a standard format. 
I have an array of time with different formatting. Here is a sample

```
["7am", "17:30", "04h50", "3.30am", "3pm30","03pm30","08:30 am", "5h00", "2h30", "5pm", "8:15"]
```

Is there a way (**or library**) that parse these inputs into Javascript time standard format?

```
["07:00 am", "05:30 pm", "04:50 am", ... "08:15 am"]
```

Comment: Take a look at moment.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) and pass an array with possible formats. The better way would be to fix the frontend though. There's type time for inputs for example.

```js
const dates = ["7am", "17:30", "04h50", "3.30am", "3pm30","03pm30","08:30 am", "5h00", "2h30", "5pm", "8:15"];

const parsed = dates.map(d => moment(d, ['ha', 'h:mm', 'h[h]mm', 'h.mma', 'hamm']))
                    .forEach(e => console.log(e.format('h:mm a')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```